# Pandas merging/filtering dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames,
the first is a list of the cities in europe that belong to the EU and
which country they're in:

cities_in_eu

country       city

0 sweden     stockholm
1 germany    berlin
2 germany    frankfurt
3 spain      barcelona
4 spain      madrid
5 france     paris
...

assume the data goes on like this for many observations, with potentially
many observations of cities for each country.

the next data frame is all cities in europe, not exclusive
to belonging in the EU.

This data frame has information on the cities population:

cities_in_europe

country         city         population(100million)

sweden         stockholm       2
germany        berlin          8
germany        frankfurt       5
spain          barcelona       6
spain          madrid          3
france         paris           8
switzerland    bern            1
russia         moscow          6
...

(the numbers here are made up)

basically i want to test the difference in population between
EU cities and non-EU cities by filtering the data to only see 
cities in/not in the EU.
Using only the data frame list of cities_in_eu, how would i
achieve this?

[image: basically i want to test the difference in population between EU cities and non-EU cities by filtering the data to only see cities in/not in the EU. Using only the data frame list of cities_in_eu, how would i achieve this?]

Comment: To clarify it, in the `cities_in_europe` you may have some cities which do not belong to EU?

Comment: yes, for example moscow is an included city in that data frame, which is a city in europe not in the eu

Comment: So the final question is that you want to remove non-EU cities in the `cities_in_europe`?

Comment: that could work, i essentially want the mean population for eu citites and another mean population number for non-eu cities, I think my formatting got messed up, see the image i posted in the main question for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

First, you will create a list of EU cities based on the `cities_in_eu`

```
EUcities = list(set(cities_in_eu.city))
```

Then you will create a table which contains all the population information of EU cities:

```
#create a list of booleans
filter = []
for city in cities_in_europe.city:
    filter.append(True if city in EUcities else False)
filtered = pd.Series(filter)
#this one will remain only cities in EU
df_eu = cities_in_europe[filtered]
nonEU_filter = [not i for i in filter]
nonEU_filtered = pd.Series(nonEU_filter)
df_non_eu = cities_in_europe[nonEU_filtered]
```

There you go, now you have 2 df of EU cities with population and non-EU cities with population. Then you can do other stuff on these two